# how to completely remove gesture recognizers

Tags: objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to remove three gesture recognizers attached to a uiscrollview.

I list them using

```
NSArray * activeScrollViewGRecs = [theScrollView gestureRecognizers];
NSLog (@"activeScrollViewGRecs count: %d",[activeScrollViewGRecs count]);
```

I get the three listed.

Then I remove them with:

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in activeScrollViewGRecs)
{
    NSLog (@"recognizer: %@",recognizer.description);
    recognizer.enabled = NO;
    [theScrollView removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}
```

Then I list them again, and get a zero count. They should be gone/removed, right ?
Why would then the view continue to respond (and gesture methods getting called) to the same touches/swipes. Is there some kind of a "flushing" mechanism that needs to happen before they're gone for good ?

this is how they get created:

```
tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handle1:)];
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO; tapGesture.delaysTouchesEnded = NO; 
tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2; tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;     
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture]; [tapGesture release];

swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handle2:)];
swipeGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO; swipeGesture.delaysTouchesEnded = NO; swipeGesture.delegate = self;
swipeGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture]; [swipeGesture release];
```

thanks

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint on those gesture methods to verify if they are indeed being fired even though you removed the gesture?

Comment: well, the methods that respond to them still get called. ie - (void)handleTouchesOne:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer) ... so stuff is still happening on the screen.

Comment: Interesting.  I've seen this happen in cases where a gesture is leaked somehow.

Comment: I would make sure those recognizers aren't re-added sometime after the for() loop and before the end of the method.

Comment: they're not. I check the gestureRecognizers NSArray at the beginning of the called gesture methods and the count is zero. so they're not attached to the view, yet they still function somehow. the app crashes in the middle of one of the methods if it gets called two or three times. as if it was not fully active anymore. very weird stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the below gesture delegate to stop any gesture:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch;
```

Comment: this is the method I'm removing them in. Now I think that might be THE problem. Removing them in the middle of a delegate method.

Comment: Why do you need to remove it? Cant you just return NO in this function?

Comment: I guess I'll have to, since I am not being able remove them properly.

Comment: You can try one more thing. Do not release the gesture recognizer object after adding it. Use the same while removing it in the function - [removeGestureRecognizer:]

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you're adding the gesture recognizers to the view but removing them from theScrollView. Is this what you intended? You should be removing the gesture recognizers from self.view if you want those to stop.

Comment: Hi. I am removing them from the same view that they're attached to. I confirm this by checking the gestureRecognizers array before and after the removal. It's 3 before and 0 after.

Comment: Scrollviews always have gesture recognizers, but the view you're adding to doesn't seem to be the one you're removing from, according to the code you've posted. Try doing it to self.view instead of theScrollView and see if that fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Adopt the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol and implement the following method.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if (to completely remove gesture recognizers)
        return NO;
    else 
        return YES;
}
```